# Angularjs: Use the json file based on user selection

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple json files as my datasource. How to use $http.get() to get the correct json files based on the user selection ?

Comment: Please first clear the requirement and what you have tried so far, without sample code and clear question its not going to work out here!

Comment: Please write a minimal, complete and varifiable question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
// Simple GET request example:
var fileName = 'myFile.txt' //name coming from where you call this service
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl/'+fileName
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

the alternative if you are using an api

```
var fileName = 'myFile.txt'
$http({
    url: url: '/someUrl', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {fileName: fileName}
 });
```